# How do I run an Async Task through IsActiveChanged

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have a Task which I'm trying to run through OnIsActiveChanged So that it runs when I open as a view. I'm sure I'm doing something obvious but I'm relatively new to Async code.
I'm getting an error with `OnIsActiveChanged` telling me

`Task SettingsView.OnIsActiveChanged(object?, EventArgs)` has the wrong return type.

Here is the method I'm trying to use:

```
    public async Task OnIsActiveChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsActive)
        {
            var streaming = _client.BiStreaming();
            var requestStream = streaming.RequestStream;
            var responseStream = streaming.ResponseStream;
    
            //Print
            Debug.WriteLine($"Duration: {Duration.TotalSeconds} seconds");
            Debug.WriteLine("");
    
            await BidirectionalStreamingExample(_client);
        }
    }
```

And here is where I am trying to call the method:

```
    public SettingsView(SequenceEditorService.SequenceEditorServiceClient client)
    {
        InitializeComponent();  
        _client = client;
        IsActiveChanged += OnIsActiveChanged;
    }
```

`IsActiveChanged` is an event handler that checks if there is a change in the state if the view. It was fine with the normal method i had but once i tried to async it broke.

Comment: What is `IsActiveChanged`? What return type does the delegate require?

Comment: Your SettingsView defines how IsActiveChanged has to look like. You can't just change that

Comment: You either have to return a `Task` or set the return type of the `OnIsActiveChanged` to `void` (which you probably want to do). I guess you copied too much code from the internet. The methods signature should look like this: `public async void OnIsActiveChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: Asking again: _"What return type does the delegate require?"_ i.e. what is `IsActiveChanged` expecting from a method assigned to it.

Comment: Thanks to @speyck for the quick tip. Return void works just fine. And the copied code works. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions to your question, as we would need to know what kind of return type the `IsActiveChanged`-event has. Typically events should have no return type (`void`) according to BCL guidelines, the possibility still exists though.

Possible solutions:

- You have to return a `Task` (very unlikely as stated above)
- Set the `OnIsActiveChanged`'s return type to `void` (likely the solution, since `IsActiveChanged` is probably a event coded by Microsoft and therefore complies with the BCL guidelines)

When applying the second solution to your code, the `OnIsActiveChanged`'s signature should look something like this:

```
public async void OnIsActiveChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```